# Bypassing Windows MAX_PATH limitation in Python

Tags: python

Using Windows 10, I am accessing a shared directory on the network. The directory has a number of nested folders holding images. The folder names tend to get pretty long. When using cv2 to read and write images, I'm getting a **"No such file or directory"** error. The length of the path is longer than **260**. I tried appending "\\?\\" to the beginning of the path, but still no luck. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

img.save() is still running into issues.

Comment: you could try to use `net use` and mount a network drive at some already deep point.

Comment: i believe `os.chdir(os.path.join(*([os.pardir] * NUM_TIMES)))` is what you looking for

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Instead I just set os.chdir() back to its original path(where code is located). I did this because the path that I pass to outputImage() is on the network and continuously changes(command line argument), and I need to be in the code directory to execute scripts. Do you see where the error is? The length is still an issue.

Comment: you can prefix your path with `'\\?\'` and windows will allow it to be long